# search for objects inside an array, based on a key with an array as a value

Tags: arrays, object

I have an array of objects and each object has an array of ids and I want to return an array of objects that have a certain id, without using es6.

```
var items = [
 {name: 'item 1', id: ['1', '2']},
 {name: 'item 2', id: ['2', '3']},
 {name: 'item 3', id: ['3']},
 {name: 'item 1', id: ['2', '4']},
];
```

I want to return all the objects that have the id of '3'

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use ES6 syntax, you can always just use good old for loops:

```
function findById(items, id){
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        for(var j = 0; j < items[i].id.length; j++)
            if(items[i].id[j] === id){
                result.push(items[i]);
                break;
            }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `id` arrays are sorted, you can do this in `O(n log k )` using binary search where `n` is number of `item`s and `k` is the size of the largest `id` array.

```
var values = [];
items.forEach( function(item) {
   var res = binarySearch( item[id], 3 );
   if ( res != -1 ) {
     values.push(item);
   }
});

function binarySearch (arr, val) {
    var lo = 0;
    var hi = arr.length - 1;

    while (lo <= hi) {
        var mid = lo + ( hi - lo ) / 2;

        if (arr[mid] === val) {
            return mid;
        }
        if (val < arr[mid]) {
            hi = mid - 1;
        } else {
            lo = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```